# Best cheap Salesforce License for users with access order object only needed

Tags: user, licenses, order, userlicense

We have more number of users consider 100 users or more.
The user which will use only standard order object record.

Now if we buy Salesforce license it will cost too much per month/user.

So, is there any way to handle it with cheap way in the case of license?
Let me know best license suitable for this scenario.

Comment: I recommend you discuss your options with your Salesforce Account Executive.

Comment: Why is this on hold? I don't think there would "too many possible answers" when you talk about **cheap** Salesforce license...

Answer (score 0):

Although you would like to check with your AE for this but looking at the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US#fntarg_9) ,the best option seems to be using customer community license .

Comment: It's restricted to be used by external user - no by employees...

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Tell me this combination will work effectively or not.  Enterprise edition - Chatter only user license - order platform permission set license    Your suggestions?

Comment: It might not work .Try in your DE org to see if you can apply the lr

Comment: Platform permission might also have cost linked to it

Comment: @Mohit  what do you say about portal licenses or community licenses? Will they help over here?

Comment: Customer community will work.There is nothing called portal license now